# How do I calculate the complexity of this leetcode solution?

Tags: python

I worked on on this problem on Leetcode called [numbers-with-same-consecutive-differences](https://leetcode.com/problems/numbers-with-same-consecutive-differences/) and have no idea why the runtime for this solution (and many others in the discussion section of that problem) is `O(2^N)`.

```
class Solution:
    def numsSameConsecDiff(self, N, K):
        """
        :type N: int
        :type K: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        ans = list(range(1, 10))
        for _ in range(N-1):
            temp = []
            for n in ans:
                prev = n % 10
                if K == 0:
                    temp.append(10 * n + prev)
                else:
                    if prev >= K:
                        temp.append(10 * n + prev - K)
                    if prev + K <= 9:
                        temp.append(10 * n + prev + K)
            ans = temp[:]
        
        return [0] + ans if N == 1 else ans
```

I get `O(N (length of integers in answers) * n (length of answer) * 2 (the two choices in the else case))`, and that is far from `O(2^n)`. Where am I misunderstanding things?

Comment: Does your solution actually pass all test cases?

Comment: What August said is the key here. You write "n (length of answer)" - but the length of answers is very much not fixed to be N, instead it is every growing, meaning that with each iteration of the outer loop you have more answers to iterate through.